# ms sql server 2005 database capacity

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

hey i have developed an web application with asp.net(c#) and ms sql server 2005 as database.
my application will add lakhs of employee data in database employee that has 3 tables 1)login table( username,password,status,type,id) 2)employee table(application number,code,first name,last name,age gender,address,occupation,state,district,pincode,taluk,gram panchayat etc) 3)family member table(name ,age,gender ,relationship)
now i wanna no how much data per table can my database hold or limit.how much such employee datas can i fill in my database?
             thanks in advance

Comment: you should better search this on google.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this and you will get all information regarding capacity of Micrsoft SQL Server 2005

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.90).aspx